# How to verify text within first column of Angular Grid in Protractor test?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, angular-grid

As part of a Protractor test on my Angular app, I am trying to validate the text within the cells in the first column of an [Angular Grid.](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/)

The below code validates the text of each cell of the grid:

```
element.all(by.css('div.ag-cell'))
  .map(function (cell) {
      return cell.getText();
      })
    .then(function (cellValues) {
        expect(cellValues).toEqual(["Toyota", "Ford", "Porsche"]);
        });
```

When ran against the below table, this code will check "Toyota", "Celica", "35000", "Ford", "Mondeo", etc. *(i.e. each cell)*

However, I want the test to only validate "Toyota", "Ford", & "Porsche" *(i.e. the first column of this [Angular Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-e2e-test-with-jasmine/))*:

[image: table]

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make for this?

*Note: If `aria-colindex="1"` `left: 0px;"` can be used as a selector, then I think I would be able to use that.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `col-id` instead of `aria-colindex`, and for you I would assume `col-id` would be `make` but I will first show you using `aria-colindex`.

```
element.all(by.css('div.ag-cell[aria-colindex="1"]'))
  .map(function (cell) {
      return cell.getText();
      })
    .then(function (cellValues) {
        expect(cellValues).toEqual(["Toyota", "Ford", "Porsche"]);
        });
```

Using `col-id`

```
element.all(by.css('div.ag-cell[col-id="make"]'))
  .map(function (cell) {
      return cell.getText();
      })
    .then(function (cellValues) {
        expect(cellValues).toEqual(["Toyota", "Ford", "Porsche"]);
        });
```

Check out CSS attribute selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp